# How to install Mesa 9.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, mesa

I want to install at least mesa 9.2. I am running 12.04 Precise Pangolin.

Lots of places suggested xorg-edgers and oibaf, but every time I type `sudo apt-get install mesa`, it says package missing.

I used to have mesa 9, but I reset my computer and now I can't find how to download it anymore.

I am trying to download and play Dota 2 on Linux. Running Dota2 and TeamFortress2 on mesa 8.0.4 is really laggy.

Comment: There is nothing called `mesa`. It is `mesa-utils`

Comment: I have downloaded mesa-utils. Entering glxinfo shows me that my mesa version is 8.0.4